# Trigger after insert on two tables

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following trigger right now but I now have the requirement to only kick off the trigger if ANOTHER table     `Facility` has a record inserted into it with a LocationID = 'ER'-

As per the comment I've updated the trigger -

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[VoceraOeOrders] ON [dbo].[OeOrders]
FOR INSERT
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Facility
        WHERE LocationID = 'ER'
        )
    RETURN

DECLARE @priority VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @cat VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @order VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @procedure VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @orderid VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @locationid VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @roomid VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @visitid VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @visitid = VisitID
    ,@priority = Priority
    ,@cat = Category
    ,@procedure = OrderedProcedureName
    ,@order = OrderDateTime
    ,@orderid = OrderNumber
    ,@locationid = (
        SELECT LocationID
        FROM dbo.Facility
        WHERE VisitID = @visitid
        )
    ,@roomid = (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN RoomTreatmentID IS NULL
                    THEN 'No Room#'
                ELSE RoomTreatmentID
                END
        FROM dbo.Facility
        WHERE VisitID = @visitid
        )
FROM insterted
WHERE @priority = 'STAT'
    AND @cat IN (
        'CT'
        ,'MRI'
        ,'XRAY'
        ,'US'
        ,'RT'
        ,'NUC'
        ,'ECHO'
        )


BEGIN
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @subject VARCHAR(500)

    SET @msg = @procedure + ' - ' + @locationid + ' ' + @roomid + '-' + ' Priority ' + @priority + '.' + 'Order DateTime/Number ' + @order + '/' + @orderid
    SET @subject = 'Vocera Group Name Here'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = N'some_email'
        ,@body = @msg
        ,@subject = @subject
        ,@profile_name = 'Alert'
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. You need to treat it as a *table*, not as something to extract single values from.

Comment: I set it up that way so that I could use each individual variable in the subject and body of the email. Is there a better way to handle that? I suppose I could move the @cat IN statement to the SET? Does that do anything performance wise?

Comment: But also I only want the email sent IF those two conditions are met. If I set the variable that way I would receive blank emails wouldn't I? Am I missing something?

Comment: Since you're calling a stored procedure, you'll need to loop - i.e. use a cursor or similar. Like I say, `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows.

Comment: I updated my code to what I think you were referring to. Is that what you meant by treating as a table? Now I'm getting what I expect but also getting some blank emails coming through. Adding a loop or cursor should help eliminate the blank emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in the beginning of you trigger:

```
if not exists(select * from facilities where FacilityID = 'ER')
return
```

You can't stop kicking trigger. You can check for some condition and return from trigger.